# Set log4j.properties for GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt, log4j

GWT compiles and creates thereby `log4j.properties` in `WEB-INF/classes`. The problem is that I can't change the settings as it gets generated and overwritten all the time.

How can I set log4j settings in Eclipse using a GWT project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT doesn't create anything in `WEB-INF/classes`; it only generates JavaScript (and possibly CSS, PNG, etc.) files in a subfolder (named after your compiled module) of the output directory (generally where the `WEB-INF/classes` also is, but that's just because several things are configured with the same output directory).
The `log4j.properties` you find there necessarily comes from elsewhere. Double-check your Maven build.